# Join tables with nearest timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, dataframe, apache-spark, dataset

I have two tables that I need to join them with nearest timestamp, but I cannot find a way to do it simply in SQL.

Example data:

```
table_1
+---------------------+------+
|      timestamp      | name |
+---------------------+------+
| 2020-02-11 14:50:00 | xxx  |
| 2020-02-11 14:51:00 | yyy  |
| 2020-02-11 14:52:00 | zzz  |
+---------------------+------+
```

```
table_2
+---------------------+-------+
|      timestamp      | value |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2020-02-11 14:49:50 |     1 |
| 2020-02-11 14:49:58 |     2 |
| 2020-02-11 14:49:59 |     3 |
| 2020-02-11 14:50:50 |    11 |
| 2020-02-11 14:50:58 |    12 |
| 2020-02-11 14:50:59 |    13 |
| 2020-02-11 14:51:50 |    21 |
| 2020-02-11 14:51:58 |    22 |
| 2020-02-11 14:51:59 |    23 |
+---------------------+-------+
```

I need to get table_1 left join table_2 with the nearest timestamp in condition that the timestamp in table_2 are always a little smaller than the one in table_1. With this logic, I'm expecting to get this result table.

```
expected result
+---------------------+------+-------+
|      timestamp      | name | value |
+---------------------+------+-------+
| 2020-02-11 14:50:00 | xxx  |     3 |
| 2020-02-11 14:51:00 | yyy  |    13 |
| 2020-02-11 14:52:00 | zzz  |    23 |
+---------------------+------+-------+
```

Can I do it with a SQL query even if it might not be vert efficient? Otherwise, I'm thinking about loading the data to spark dataframe. Do we have this kind of algorithme implemented in spark ?

Thanks

Comment: Yep, you can do it with a query. Efficiency won't be a problem

Comment: Thanks, but how ? I cannot figure it out. Do you have an example.

Comment: Please make up your mind what environment you want to use ([tag:mysq] or [tag:apache-spark]) and [edit] your question accordingly. These are two different systems, with different supported features and incompatible SQL dialects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*,
       (select t2.value
        from table_2 t2
        where t2.timestamp <= t1.timestamp
        order by t2.timestamp desc
        limit 1
       ) as t2_value
from table_1 t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the `value` from `table_2`, I'd use Gordon's answer. But if you need to select more columns, I would use a correlated subquery in the LEFT JOINs ON clause:

```
select t1.timestamp, t1.name, t2.value
from table_1 t1
left join table_2 t2 on t2.timestamp = (
  select max(t2i.timestamp)
  from table_2 t2i
  where t2i.timestamp <= t1.timestamp
)
```

Result:

```
| timestamp           | name | value |
| ------------------- | ---- | ----- |
| 2020-02-11 14:50:00 | xxx  | 3     |
| 2020-02-11 14:51:00 | yyy  | 13    |
| 2020-02-11 14:52:00 | zzz  | 23    |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mwtDgVWV2hh3dA3fNgnGyN/0)

Comment: And why a LEFT JOIN?

Comment: @Strawberry just wait....        LEFT JOIN because OP explicitly asked: "I need to get table_1 left join table_2".

Comment: i suspect the OP didn't know what they were saying - it seems odd to want to return a null result here (but of course I could be completely wrong)

Comment: @Strawberry I don't know if a LEFT JOIN is necessary for the real task - But there clearly can be reasons. If you want all rows from `t1` regardless of the existence of a smaller timestamp in `t2` - You need a LEFT JOIN. Only the `value` column will be NULL in the result, if the JOIN finds no matches.